# CallMethodAction in Silverlight doesn't work

Tags: silverlight

How to use CallMethodAction?
It doesn't work.

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
  <i:EventTrigger>
    <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="Init" />
  </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Init method is in view model

```
    public void Init()
    {
        if (_hasEmails != true)
        {
            IsBusy = true;

            _service.GetListAsync();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't specified a `TargetObject` try this:-

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers> 
  <i:EventTrigger> 
    <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="Init" TargetObject="{Binding}" /> 
  </i:EventTrigger> 
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```